# Small non-measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

The standard construction of a subset of [0,1] that is not Lebesgue measurable gives a set with the property that any measurable subset has measure 0. (We might think of these as "small" non-measurable sets.) Suppose two sets (measurable or not) have this property, i.e., that any measurable subset is a set of measure zero. Does the union of these two sets also have this property? One interesting case is when each set, as well as the union, is non-measurable.

Comment: "i.e., that any measurable subset is a **null** set." Shoud this be "i.e., that any measurable subset is a set of measure zero." ?

Comment: Look up Bernstein sets.

Comment: In some mathematical dialects null set means set of measure zero rather than empty set. That was my intent, but, yes, measure zero is clearer.

Comment: The technical word for your "small" is "inner-measure zero".

Comment: Ah, I see. Both the Bernstein set and its complement have said property and their union (the real line ) does not, so my question is answered in the negative. Not the answer I was pulling for, but I'll soldier on. Thanks!

Comment: For more about Bernstein sets, see [this 5 Feb 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/sxp7dgz9zTYJ) (minor correction [here](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/QaaZ0eMcoGQJ)). Also, see  [this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/119693/15780) and [these MSE questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bernstein+set%22+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com) and [these mathoverflow questions](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=%22Bernstein+set%22).